# Como criar transições personalizadas no Android Studio?

Tags: android, animação, transição

Gostaria de saber como fazer transições personalizadas no Android. As transições entre as atividades são sempre as mesmas. Tem algum tutorial que ensine a melhorar as transições?

Comment: A resposta te ajudou ou precisa de mais algum exemplo?

Answer (score 6):

Para criar animações customizadas entre transições de telas na aplicação, pode-se usar o método [`overridePendingTransition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) da sua classe pública [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Sua sintaxe é:

```
public void overridePendingTransition(int animacaoEntrada, int animacaoSaida)
```

> Tem algum tutorial que ensine a melhorar as transições?

Sim, existem [vários tutoriais](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=transitions%20layout%20animation%20android&*), mas vou lhe dar um pequeno resumo. Quanto a melhoria das transições, vai da criatividade da cada uma.

Veja bem, existem algumas transições padrões dentro do diretório `android.R.anim` como por exemplo `fade_in` e `fade_out`. Então aplicando essa animação seria desta forma:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EnterActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Isso  fará com que saia do *layout* suavemente usando a *tag* `alpha`, como por exemplo o `fade_in`. Veja:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_quad"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Para criar uma animação customizada, basta, de preferência, criar diretório com o nome `anim` no seu *resource*, e inserir o arquivo de animação como por exemplo [`botton_in` e `top_out`](https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/1d97213643aaa0a77a9e2245a29dd283#file-top_out-xml) que fará com que o layout que chamado virá de baixo para cima, diferente da transição padrão. Veja como seria:

#### botton_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="150"/>
</set>
```

#### top_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="150"/>
</set>
```

#### Classe

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EnterActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.botton_in, R.anim.top_out);
```

O tema do Material fornece algumas animações padrão para botões e transições de atividades e o Android 5.0 (API de nível 21) e posteriores permitem a personalização dessas animações e a criação de novas. Você pode ver em [Como definir animações personalizadas](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Obrigado Ack Lay...mas tem um porem..como eu implemento isso no MainActivity?

Comment: @legolas quando você mudar de uma atividade para outra. Para mudar você usa o Intent. O código está aí na resposta.

Comment: Valeu...ja vi aqui